# Java GUI : JLabel as Bullet should fly through Jpanel, gives only "result"

Tags: java, user-interface

first off: I'm pretty new in this stuff, but highly interested. I'm pretty sure the answer to my problem is already out there somewhere, but I can't really understand it because of the lack of knowledge.

Straight to the Problem:

JLabel player : The Label which you control
JLabel bullet : The Label which you shoot, when triggered (alerady solved in the main class)

```
public class Shoot extends Thread {

  public Shoot(JLabel bullet, JLabel player) {

    bullet.setLocation(player.getX(),player.getY());
    int bulletX = player.getX();
    int bulletY = player.getY();

    for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
       bullet.setText("o"); 
       bullet.setLocation(bulletX,bulletY - 20); 

       try {
         sleep(200);
       }catch (InterruptedException ie){} 

       bullet.setText("");        
     }
   }
}
```

The problem here is, that the "progress" of the bullet isn't visible. I want that the bullet is seen while it is still flying and disappear when the range is reached. (When i = 20)

Please help me

Dennis

Comment: If you're doing anything with a lot of movement. You **really** don't want to use Swing (javax.swing.JLabel for example). There are a *ton* of libraries out there that handle movement and physics automatically.

Comment: Are you doing this .setLocation in the event loop?  That's a big mistake because nothing will render until the bullet stops flying.  You need to do this in a different thread, and call .paint occasionally.

Comment: @Paul: no need to use a different thread directly. Better to simply use a Swing Timer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the solution is out there: don't call Thread.sleep(...) on the Swing event thread as this will put your entire GUI to sleep. Instead, use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score 1):

You subclasses `Thread` so I assume you wish to run your loop in the thread. To do this, you should override `run` (having your code in the `Shoot` constructor is just a method call):

```
public class Shoot extends Thread {
    JLabel bullet; 
    JLabel player;

    public Shoot(JLabel bullet, JLabel player) {
        this.bullet = bullet;
        this.player = player;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Your code from here on...
        bullet.setLocation(player.getX(),player.getY());
        int bulletX = player.getX();
        int bulletY = player.getY();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
            bullet.setText("o"); 
            bullet.setLocation(bulletX,bulletY - 20); 

            try {
                sleep(200);
            }catch (InterruptedException ie){} 

            bullet.setText("");        
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere you probably do this:

```
Shoot shoot = new Shoot(bullet, player);
```

To actually let the thread run, add this line:

```
shoot.start();
```

Now comes the bad part: You should not call most Swing methods outside of the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). The EDT is very probably the one where you create the instance of `Shoot`. The thread in the Shoot class is different from the EDT. To call Swing methods from there, you need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        bullet.setText("o"); 
        bullet.setLocation(bulletX,bulletY - 20); 
    }
});
```

You might use the Thread based approach to learn about this. If your code shall be more than an exercise, you should not be fixed on Swing. (As already mentioned in the other comments and answers)

If you want to go the multithreading Swing route, you might want to look at `SwingWorker` and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` and remember to be cautious of the methods you can call outside the `EDT`.